# c++: reassigning const char in function

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants

```
void func(const char *s){
    char *result = new char[strlen(s)];
    strcpy(result, "new stuff");
    s = result;    
}

int main(){
    const char *str = "old stuff";
    func(str);
    std::cout << str << "\n";
    return 0; 
}
```

The code above compiles without fuss, but `str` is not changed (still prints out "old stuff"). Why is this? As far as I know, `str` should be passed by reference into the function, and I should be able to reassign a `const char *` to point to something else.

Comment: Hint: It is passed by value.

Comment: *As far as I know, str should be passed by reference into the function* how would it be passed by reference, its not a reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: well, that was silly. dumb question, thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: Note that result* is not large enough to contain "new stuff", so UB.

Comment: 1. Don't use C strings if you do not have to. 2, Do not forget `'\0'` at the end of the string constants. 3. Don't forget to `delete[]` memory which has been allocated using `new[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code above compiles without fuss

This is expected, because you are not doing anything out of the ordinary (apart from leaking memory, of course).

> but `str` is not changed (still prints out `"old stuff"`). Why is this?

This is because `s` of `func` is a copy of `str` pointer from `main`. Re-assigning this pointer makes what used to be a copy point to some other location; the original remains unchanged, though.

> As far as I know, `str` should be passed by reference into the function, and I should be able to reassign a `const char *` to point to something else.

Nothing is passed by reference implicitly; you must specify that a function takes its argument by reference, otherwise it's passed by value. This includes pointers.

The fix required to make your function do what you expect is very small: add an ampersand in front of `s`.

```
void func(const char *&s){
    // Don't forget to add 1 for null terminator
    char *result = new char[strlen(s)+1];
    strcpy(result, "new stuff");
    s = result;    
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/z8xzsc)

Comment: thanks. clearly i've been away from C/C++ for too long.

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(const char *s){
    char *result = new char[strlen(s)];
    strcpy(result, "new stuff");
    s = result;    
}
```

it is not changed because `s` is local copy of original pointer which caller passed from `main`. Just it is pointing to same address as original pointer. So when you are doing this assignment, only the value of local copy gets changed.